# Can i install .ipa file from my Existing App?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipa

I want to install .ipa file from my existing app.The .ipa file is in my app bundle.I am making sure that profile contains UDID of the Device.I want to install new app when user clicks on  button my .ipa should be installed in to the same device. Is it possible or not? I don't have jailbreak device.it's registered device.

Comment: NOT from inside the app, but YES by calling a service to trigger a download..

Comment: UDID is no longer available in iOS 6+. But you can use URL Scheme to detect if the user has installed the app or not.